# Why won't this new line start a new row in the output csv file?

Tags: php, csv

I've read all the other post regarding newline and csv files and none of them work for this.

```
header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=affiliate_emails_from".$from."_to_".$to.".csv");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");


echo 'First name,Last name,Email \r\n';
foreach($account_emails as $value) echo $value['first_name'].','.$value['last_name'].','.$value['email'].' \r\n';
```

Can someone please help change this to start new rows in the csv file? A restriction of my assignment is that I can't write the file to the server and then link to it. I have to output the file directly to browser as a download.

Thanks

In case someone comes accross this:

```
echo 'First name,Last name,Email \r\n'; //won't work
echo "First name,Last name,Email \r\n"; // works
```

Comment: Because `\r` and `\n` only have any special meaning when in double quotes (`"`)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php Read about different quote types.

Comment: Now stop trying to build your own CSV functionality and start using PHP's built-in [fputcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php)

Comment: I'm not allowed to write the file to the server for this assignment.

Comment: In the case of: echo 'First name,Last name,Email \r\n'; changing it to "\r" or "\n" or "\r\n" or "\r" "\n" don't work. Please show me how it should be. Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: ok, I got it now. Thanks.

Comment: try using PHP_EOL - constant, so your code is doing fine even on LINUX or Mac

Comment: You don't need to write the file to the server, write to a special file called `php://output` if it has to be sent directly to the browser

Answer (score 1):

You should be using fputcsv() function for this, then each time you call that function counts as a new row.

You don't need to save the CSV before offing it as a download either.

```
// output headers so that the file is downloaded rather than displayed
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=guarantees.csv');

// create a file pointer connected to the output stream
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

// output the column headings
fputcsv($output, array('First Name', 'Last Name'));
```

So on and so on. Each time you call the function, its a new row in the CSV.